# Restart the currently running script?

Tags: powershell

Alrighty, so I've got this much down.

```
# Prompts the script user to confirm that the account from
# $userName is indeed the one they want to Terminate
function Get-Confirmation {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $userName
    )

    $confirmMessage = 'Are you sure that {0} is the user that you want to terminate?' -f $userName

    $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue($confirmMessage, 'Terminate User?')
}

# Code that populates $userName and starts the Termination process
if (Get-Confirmation -User $userName) {
    # If  confirmation == True: start Termination

    # Copy user's security groups to $groups.txt in their user folder
    Out-File $logFilePath -InputObject $userNameGroups.memberOf -Encoding utf8

    # TODO: Remove $userName's security groups from AD Object
    # Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $userNameGroups -Confirm:$false

    Copy-Item -Path "\\path\to\active\user\folder" ` 
        -Destination "\\path\to\terminated\user\folder"
} else {
    # Don't Terminate
    # TODO: Restart script to select another user
}
```

So my question is: how do I satisfy the TODO in the `else` statement? I've searched online, but the only thing that has come up is restarting the computer. I just want the script to be re-run. Is it as simple as `./scriptName`?

Comment: Why would you need to restart the script? Why not just have the if-then in a while loop?

Comment: @EBGreen If the user input was incorrect, it would restart to prompt them to input another user name. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: @MFonner Yes. Assign the return value of your function to a variable, so you can use the result in more than one place.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It all makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than "Restarting" your script you could check that the input is correct before even "Starting" your script, if all the input is correct there won't be any need to "Restart" :)

Here a Do-While loop is used to check that a username exists in AD before proceeding to the script below:

```
$message = "Please enter the username you'd like to terminate"

Do
{
    # Get a username from the user
    $getUsername = Read-Host -prompt $message

    Try
    {
        # Check if it's in AD
        $checkUsername = Get-ADUser -Identity $getUsername -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch
    {
        # Couldn't be found
        Write-Warning -Message "Could not find a user with the username: $getUsername. Please check the spelling and try again."

        # Loop de loop (Restart)
        $getUsername = $null
    }
}
While ($getUsername -eq $null)

# Do-While succeeded so username is correct
# Put script to run if input is correct here
```

Comment: wow. I can't believe I wasn't thinking of it this way. Thanks!